# Docker-Compose Configuring Container Timezone

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a python application that run in docker. In application, I am using datetime.now() function and this function takes value from container timezone. So I should configure container timezone.

My directory structure:

```
- myapp (project folder)
- DockerFile
- docker-compose.yml
- requirement.txt
- run.py
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV TZ=Europe/Istanbul
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential

COPY . /app
ENV HOME=/app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV LOGIN_USERNAME=master_login_username
ENV LOGIN_PASSWORD=master_login_password

ENV SLAVE_LOGIN_USERNAME=slave_login_username
ENV SLAVE_LOGIN_PASSWORD=slave_login_password

ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=....
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=....
ENV CLUSTER_NAME=....

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn","-b","0.0.0.0:5000","-w","1","myapp:create_app()","--access-logfile","/app/myapp/logs/access.log","--error-logfile","/app/myapp/logs/error.log","--timeout","90"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  master:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    container_name: master
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/master
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/usr/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
networks:
  default:
    name: master
```

So, Actually in Dockerfile I configure timezone. But I am building with `docker-compose up --build` and container timezone doesn't change.

When I build without compose as `docker build -t` and run with `docker run --name slave -d -p 80:5000` timezone is changes as I want to.

What am I missing ?

Thanks and best regards..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem. Actually, I checked /usr/share/zoneinfo folder is exists. And I saw that not exists. So, Tzdata package is missing. I added line in Dockerfile `apt-get install tzdata -y` and solved my problem.

Answer (score 7):

Updating `/etc/timezone` is the usual way, but, at least in my case, I had to do something else: create a link from the desired time zone to `etc/localtime` and reconfigure `tzdata` (install it first, if you don't have it):

```
# Set TimeZone to Spain (mainland)
ENV TZ=Europe/Madrid
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set environment variable in docker-compose

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  master:
    build: .
    environment:
      - "TZ=Europe/Istanbul" 
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    container_name: master
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/master
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/usr/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
networks:
  default:
    name: master
```

Comment: thanks dude, but actually, tzdata package was missing :) ı solved problem

Comment: You have set environment twice in master, it should raise an error. You should correct this by putting "TZ=Europe/Istanbul" bellow MONGO_URI